# Plone 4x: Can I get the title of a folder for the page content

Tags: plone

I was wondering if I could get the folder title for page content in a template. Right now the code in the template is:

```
<div>
<metal:field use-macro:"python:here.widget('title', mode='view')">
Title
</metal:field>
</div>
```

This is for a news item. I would like to change this so that instead of the title of the news item, it would be the the title of the parent folder for the news item. I am new to Plone. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you ever need more help, post questions to our forum https://community.plone.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your div with something like:

```
<div>
    <h1 id="parent-fieldname-title" class="documentFirstHeading"
        tal:content="python:context.aq_parent.title">
       Title
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: To make sure the context won't be a possible default-view-content-item, change `context.aq_parent` to `context.aq_parent.aq_inner`.